# Slide elements in from left AND right at the same time?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have two elements .show slide in on a single click. I'd like the first element (an img) to slide in from the left and the other element (a div) to slide in from the right on click of a button (a div). Then, when another button is clicked, I'd like the first two elements to fade away and the next two elements (corresponding to the button clicked) slide in.

Anyone know how I can accomplish this? I'm very new to JQuery. This is what I have for the html.

```
<div id="button1">Button1</div>
<div id="button2">Button2</div>
<div id="button3">Button3</div>

<div id="container">
<img id="slideleft1" src="img.png">
<div id="slideright1">I need this div to slide in from the right.</div>
</div>

    <div id="container">
<img id="slideleft2" src="img.png">
<div id="slideright2">I need this div to slide in from the right.</div>
</div>

    <div id="container">
<img id="slideleft3" src="img.png">
<div id="slideright3">I need this div to slide in from the right.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify... on click of what? Do <div> & <img> exist already & are hidden or will they be created on-the-fly on Click?

Comment: Oops! Sorry about that. I clarified a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $container = $( '#container' );
var $left = $( '#slideleft', $container ); // handle to the image
var $right = $( '#slideright', $container ); // handle to the div

// apply some styles to the container (could also be done with pure css)
$container.css( {
    'position'      : 'relative', // to use absolute positions inside
    'left'          : '0px',
    'top'           : '0px'
} );

// positionate the image outside from the container and hide it
$left.css( {
    'postion'       : 'absolute',
    'left'          : (-$left.width()) + 'px',
    'opacity'       : '0'
} );

// positionate the div outside from the container and hide it
$right.css( {
    'postion'       : 'absolute',
    'right'          : (-$right.width()) + 'px',
    'opacity'       : '0'
} );


// will be executed when the event "slideIn" is triggered to your container element
$( '#container' ).on( 'slideIn', function() {

    var $container = $( this );
    var $left = $( '#slideleft', $container ); // handle to the image
    var $right = $( '#slideright', $container ); // handle to the div

    // slide and fade in the left image
    $left.animate( {
        'left'      : '0px',
        'opacity'   : '1'
    } );

    // slide and fade in the right div
    $right.animate( {
        'right'      : '0px',
        'opacity'   : '1'
    } );

} );
```

to trigger the event you could write something like this in your html

```
<a onclick="$('#container').trigger('slideIn');">click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, this should solve your problem:

```
$('#slideleft').animate({
    marginLeft: '50px'
  }, 1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
$('#slideright').animate({
    marginRight: '200px'
  }, 1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
```

​See the demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/be3qc/).

This is not exact solution, you can modify it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to bukfixart answer, you may also want to cover the case where someone is clicking rapidly on whatever should trigger the animation.

CSS:

```
#container{position:relative; background:silver; height:400px;}
#slideleft{ background:red; width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute;}
#sliderig
```

ht{ background:blue ; width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; right:0}​

JS:

```
var shown = true;
$('body').click(function() {
    if(!$("#slideleft").is(':animated')) {
        if (shown) {        
          $('#slideleft').animate({
              left:"-100px"
          }, 500, function() {
              shown = !shown;
          });
          $('#slideright').animate({
              right:"-100px"
          }, 500, function() {
          });
        } else {
          $('#slideleft').animate({
              left:"0px"
          }, 500, function() {
              shown = !shown;
          });
          $('#slideright').animate({
              right:"0px"
          }, 500, function() {
          });
        }
    }
});
```

​

Here, have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rm4zy/